# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Converting varchar to date using column as a variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, converters

I have a column made up of dates, like "20141030", but they column property is varchar(8).  I need to query this column in order to do comparisons on it to pull the correct information for a report.

This is my original code but returns no data:

```
select appt_date 
from appointments 
where convert(date,appt_date,112) 
between getdate() and dateadd(month,-24,getdate())
```

Same with this one:

```
select appt_date 
from appointments 
where convert(date,appt_date,112) 
between convert(date,getdate(),112) and dateadd(month,-24,convert(date,getdate(),112))
```

Then I saw an example that was posted so I tried it, but I don't know what to put as the expression for the convert function because it's not a constant. I want it to be a variable of the column, but it gives me the error below:

```
declare @ColumnName varchar(8)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @ColumnName = 'appt_date' + convert(date,appt_date,112)
set @sql = 'select ' + @ColumnName + ' from appointments'
```

*Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'appt_date'.*

So, how do I go about finding the varchar dates in the appt_date column that are 24 months back from today?

Comment: Instead of using `112` as style format, use `101`. Again, never store datetime as varchar.

Comment: If your datatype is varchar(8) you do NOT have a column of dates, you have a column of varchar(8) values that may or may not be able to converted to a date datatype.I would also ask why your column names are dates? Does your table have a column for every date?

Comment: Sean, they are dates.  The column name is "appt_date".  It's in a database that was already created by a healthcare EMR vendor.  I didn't set the property to varchar.  Hence, i needed to convert those values to dates, which I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the earlier date FIRST in the BETWEEN clause:

```
 between dateadd(month,-24,getdate()) and getdate()
```

Comment: OMG!!  Thanks, Tab!  It's always something simple that gets overlooked.  Ugh!

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast it to datetime like this

```
cast(appt_date as datetime)
```

or to date (only possible on SQL Server 2008 or later)

```
cast(appt_date as date)
```

so your query (including swapping the first and last values of the BETWEEN operator, so that the oldest comes first) will be something like

```
select appt_date
from appointments
where cast(appt_date as datetime)
      between dateadd(month,-24,getdate()) and getdate()
```

Also, note that getdate() actually returns a datetime that holds the current date ***and time***, not just the current date. To get only the date (i.e. a datetime with 00:00:00.000 as the time part), use

```
dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0)
```

so your query would then be something like

```
select appt_date
from appointments
where cast(appt_date as datetime)
      between
      dateadd(month,-24,dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0))
      and
      dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0)
```